# Can a value be passed in to a computed value in Vue composition?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to improve my understanding of Vue.js and I was wondering if a value can be passed into computed()? I typically use the composition api and the anonymous function of computed seems like a value *could* be passed in, but I don't know where it would come from or what it would do.

This is how I normally create a computed value:

```js
<script setup>
const myComputedVal = computed(() => {
return val1 - val2
})
</script>
```

So is the () at the start of the computed only for initiating the anonymous function, or could a value be passed in some how? And if it were, how exactly would it be passed in?

I assume the answer is simply 'no you can't', but I'm just trying to understand some of the Vue reactivity better. I have already read the [computed docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed).

Comment: Could be computed(() => val => ...), but there's not much benefit from such a computed Consider explaining your case, this could be XY problem. What are val1 and val2, where do they come from and how is myComputedVal  used?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the values comes from the outer scope (refs, reactives or props, imported and injected also or returned from function/methods (imported also)). Using non-reactive values doesn't make sense since the computed won't be ever updated. A computed is a ref itself, a ref is a reactive variable, there's no arguments to pass, like for a property of an object, you just have a getter and an optional setter (if writable).

```
    <script setup>
    const props = defineProps({val2:Number});
    const val1 = ref('');
    const myComputedVal = computed(() => {
    return val1.value - props.val2;
    })
    </script>
```